# How do I swap tensor's axes in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, axis, swap, axes, permute

I have a tensor of shape `(30, 116, 10)`, and I want to swap the first two dimensions, so that I have a tensor of shape `(116, 30, 10)`

I saw that numpy as such a function implemented (`np.swapaxes`) and I searched for something similar in tensorflow but I found nothing.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[`tf.transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) provides the same functionality as `np.swapaxes`, although in a more generalized form. In your case, you can do `tf.transpose(orig_tensor, [1, 0, 2])` which would be equivalent to `np.swapaxes(orig_np_array, 0, 1)`.

Comment: What if I don't know the dimensions of my input tensor but I'm sure I want to swap the last 2 axes? Like, what should I do to a tensor variable so that an input of shape `(2, 3, 4, 5)` will end up as `(2, 3, 5, 4)` but the same should work on an input of shape `(3, 4, 5, 6, 7)` (and turn it into `(3, 4, 5, 7, 6)`)

Comment: @KonstantinosBairaktaris see my answer

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to use [tf.einsum](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum) to swap axes if the number of input dimensions is unknown. For example:

- `tf.einsum("ij...->ji...", input)` will swap the first two dimensions of `input`;
- `tf.einsum("...ij->...ji", input)` will swap the last two dimensions;
- `tf.einsum("aij...->aji...", input)` will swap the second and the third
  dimension;
- `tf.einsum("ijk...->kij...", input)` will permute the first three dimensions;

and so on.

Comment: I've heard `tf.einsum` is really slow

Answer (score 6):

You can transpose just the last two axes with [`tf.linalg.matrix_transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matrix_transpose), or more generally, you can swap any number of trailing axes by working out what the leading indices are dynamically, and using relative indices for the axes you want to transpose

```py
x = tf.ones([5, 3, 7, 11])
trailing_axes = [-1, -2]

leading = tf.range(tf.rank(x) - len(trailing_axes))   # [0, 1]
trailing = trailing_axes + tf.rank(x)                 # [3, 2]
new_order = tf.concat([leading, trailing], axis=0)    # [0, 1, 3, 2]
res = tf.transpose(x, new_order)
res.shape                                             # [5, 3, 11, 7]
```