# Swap tensor axes in TensorFlow without tf.transpose

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a tensor of unknown shape, but it is at least 3 dimensional, i.e. `shape=[a, b, c, ...]`.
I would like to switch dimensions `a` and `b`, without knowing how long the tensor is (so I can't use tf.transpose, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212205/swap-tensor-axes-in-tensorflow))

Comment: did you find a better solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

This works, but is ugly:

```
tf.transpose(x, [1, 0] + [i+2 for i in range(tf.shape(x).shape[0]-2)])
```

Comment: You can use `tf.rank()` instead of `tf.shape()`: `tf.transpose(x, tf.concat([[1,0], tf.range(2, tf.rank(x))], 0)`