# Perform tf.signal.fft2d in the middle of the tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, fft

I have a `tf.Tensor` of, for example, shape `(31, 6, 6, 3)`.

I want to perform [tf.signal.fft2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/fft2d) on the shapes `6, 6` so, in other words, in the middle. However, the description says:

> Computes the 2-dimensional discrete Fourier transform over the **inner-most** 2 dimensions of input

I could do it with a for loop but I fear it might be very ineffective. Is there a fastest way?

The result must have the same output shape of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212205/how-do-i-swap-tensors-axes-in-tensorflow) I implemented this solution using [tf.transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose):

```
in_pad = tf.transpose(in_pad, perm=[0, 3, 1, 2])
out = tf.signal.fft2d(tf.cast(in_pad, tf.complex64))
out = tf.transpose(out, perm=[0, 2, 3, 1])
```